# Reference request - Measure of sphere in Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Consider a smooth $2$-dimensional closed Riemannian manifold $M$ and $x \in M$. Let $ 0 < r< \text{inj}(M) $ and let $\mathcal{H}^1$ be the Hausdorff measure  induced by the Riemannian distance. Where can I find a proof of the fact that there exists a positive constant $C$ s.t.
$$ \mathcal{H}^1(\partial B(x,r)) \le Cr $$
?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not true. You can just consider the upper half plane with its usual hyperbolic metric.

Comment: Could you please expand your comment? Is the upper half plane a closed Riemannian manifold?

Comment: If your manifold is closed, then your statement is vacuous for big values of $r$. So if the upper half-plane provides a counterexample for small $r$, and you insist on having a closed counterexample, you could take any closed quotient of the upper half plane (ie a hyperbolic surface). Right?